# RoR ActiveRecord Query producing unexpected result

Tags: ruby-on-rails, active-record-query

I have a test app with models as follows

```
ActiveRecord::Schema.define(version: 20140102023300) do

  create_table "customers", force: true do |t|
    t.string   "name"
    t.datetime "created_at"
    t.datetime "updated_at"
  end

  create_table "order_products", force: true do |t|
    t.integer  "customer_id"
    t.integer  "order_id"
    t.integer  "product_id"
    t.datetime "created_at"
    t.datetime "updated_at"
  end

  create_table "orders", force: true do |t|
    t.text     "description"
    t.integer  "customer_id"
    t.datetime "created_at"
    t.datetime "updated_at"
  end

  create_table "products", force: true do |t|
    t.string   "description"
    t.float    "item_price"
    t.datetime "created_at"
    t.datetime "updated_at"
  end

end
```

The associations are as follows

```
class Customer < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :orders
end

class Order < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :customer
  has_many :order_products
end

class OrderProduct < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :order
end
```

Then I have seeded the database with seeds.rb as follows:

```
customers = Customer.create([{:name => 'Alex'}, {:name => 'Clare'}, {:name => 'Bob'}, {:name => 'Ian'}])

orders = Order.create([  
  {:description => 'description for order 1',:customer_id => 1},
  {:description => 'description for order 2',:customer_id => 2},
  {:description => 'description for order 3',:customer_id => 2},
  {:description => 'description for order 4',:customer_id => 1},
  {:description => 'description for order 5',:customer_id => 4}
  ])

orderproducts = OrderProduct.create([
  {:customer_id => 1, :order_id => 1, :product_id => 1},
  {:customer_id => 1, :order_id => 1, :product_id => 2},
  {:customer_id => 1, :order_id => 2, :product_id => 4},
  {:customer_id => 1, :order_id => 2, :product_id => 7},
  {:customer_id => 1, :order_id => 2, :product_id => 3},
  {:customer_id => 2, :order_id => 1, :product_id => 5},
  {:customer_id => 2, :order_id => 1, :product_id => 6},
  {:customer_id => 2, :order_id => 2, :product_id => 3},
  {:customer_id => 2, :order_id => 2, :product_id => 4},
  ])

products = Product.create([
  {:description => 'teddy bear', :item_price => 19.95},
  {:description => 'doll', :item_price => 24.00},
  {:description => 'lego', :item_price => 16.00},
  {:description => 'toy truck', :item_price => 29.95},
  {:description => 'crayons pk10', :item_price => 17.90},
  {:description => 'sketch pad', :item_price => 21.50},
  {:description => 'football', :item_price => 10.55},
  ])
```

Then in Rails Console I am loading up a variable with the list of customers:

```
@customers = Customer.all
```

When I run this command: `@customers.find(1).orders` I correctly get

```
Order id: 1, description: "description for order 1", customer_id: 1, created_at: "2014-01-02 02:51:36", updated_at: "2014-01-02 02:51:36">, 

Order id: 4, description: "description for order 4", customer_id: 1, created_at: "2014-01-02 02:51:36", updated_at: "2014-01-02 02:51:36">]
```

I then want to query the items within each order. For simplicity lets say **I want to find the products within order 1, for Customer 1**.

I tried this query: `@customers.find(1).orders.find(1).order_products` but I get this result:

```
OrderProduct id: 1, customer_id: 1, order_id: 1, product_id: 1, created_at: "2014-01-02 02:51:36", updated_at: "2014-01-02 02:51:36">,

OrderProduct id: 2, customer_id: 1, order_id: 1, product_id: 2, created_at: "2014-01-02 02:51:36", updated_at: "2014-01-02 02:51:36">, 

OrderProduct id: 6, customer_id: 2, order_id: 1, product_id: 5, created_at: "2014-01-02 02:51:36", updated_at: "2014-01-02 02:51:36">, 

OrderProduct id: 7, customer_id: 2, order_id: 1, product_id: 6, created_at: "2014-01-02 02:51:36", updated_at: "2014-01-02 02:51:36">
```

It looks like it is returning the results for the `orders.find(1).order_products` part of the query because all the results are `order_id: 1`. The problem is that this result set includes results for `customer_id: 1` and `2`.

What I actually want to see is the products within `order 1`, for `customer 1`. Can you help me understand the correct query that I need please?

Comment: Looks like you have some issues with your seed data. I've posted a solution that suggests 1) a fix as-is, and 2) a way to rectify the seed data so that your original query works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your query is basically returning all a list of `OrderProduct` that belong to an `Order` – the way you've structured your query, it's basically agnostic to the `User` the `Order` belongs to. For instance – according to your schema – customer #1 has order #1, but order #1 also belongs to customer #2. Because the query is for the order products that belong to an order, order #1 will return entries for both customer #1 *and* customer #2.

Because `OrderProduct` has foreign keys to both `Customer` and `Order`, you can try a more explicit query for retrieving the order products that belong to a *specific* customer **and** order:

```
OrderProduct.where(:customer_id => 1, :order_id => 1)
```

**UPDATE**:

You have some issues in your `seeds.rb` that are resulting in convoluted relationships. You've defined that `Order` belongs to `Customer`, but your database seed suggests that orders belong to *multiple* customers.

```
orderproducts = OrderProduct.create([
  {:customer_id => 1, :order_id => 1, :product_id => 1},
  {:customer_id => 1, :order_id => 1, :product_id => 2},
  {:customer_id => 1, :order_id => 2, :product_id => 4},
  {:customer_id => 1, :order_id => 2, :product_id => 7},
  {:customer_id => 1, :order_id => 2, :product_id => 3},
  {:customer_id => 2, :order_id => 1, :product_id => 5}, # Order 1 already belongs to Customer 1
  {:customer_id => 2, :order_id => 1, :product_id => 6}, # Order 1 already belongs to Customer 1
  {:customer_id => 2, :order_id => 2, :product_id => 3}, # Order 2 already belongs to Customer 1
  {:customer_id => 2, :order_id => 2, :product_id => 4}, # Order 2 already belongs to Customer 1
  ])
```

Once you've ensured that each order is associated with *a single* customer, you can issue the your original query to retrieve the order products belonging to a user's order:

```
@customers.find(1).orders.find(1).order_products
#=> OrderProduct id: 1, customer_id: 1, order_id: 1, product_id: 1, created_at: "2014-01-02 02:51:36", updated_at: "2014-01-02 02:51:36">,
#=> OrderProduct id: 2, customer_id: 1, order_id: 1, product_id: 2, created_at: "2014-01-02 02:51:36", updated_at: "2014-01-02 02:51:36">,
```

Comment: Brilliant zeantsoi!! I am always very grateful for the guidance of experts. Thankyou so much. :-)

Comment: Zeantsoi, can I ask one more question please? Would you remove the customer_id from the OrderProcuct model's schema altogether? (and the corresponding seed data)

Comment: A note for other Ruby Noobies like me: @customers.find(1).orders.find(1).order_products does return the products for that order but @customers.find(1).orders.find(2).order_products fails because the next order_id for this customer is 4. So @customers.find(1).orders.find(4).order_products works. If you want to enumerate / iterate the orders for customer, use @customers.find(1).orders[0] to access the array (ActiveRecord::Associations::CollectionProxy: object)

Comment: I would, as your `Customer` model currently has no defined relationship to `OrderProduct` (so the relationship effectively is non-existent, unless through the intervening `Order` model). You should probably look into [`has_many :through`](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#the-has-many-through-association) – this is a perfect use case for that particular relationship.

Answer (score 0):

If you know the `customer_id` and `order_id`, you can query `OrderProduct` as such

```
OrderProduct.where(customer_id: 1, order_id: 1)
```

However you can also exploit active record associations to have something like

```
Customer.find(1).orders.first.order_products # to get all order_products of the first order of the customer.
```

OR

```
Customer.find(1).where(order_id: 1).order_products
```

Refer to this excellent guide from [the docs](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html)

Comment: Wow... the first part of your answer looks oddly familiar. But the second part is simply rehashing the code from the OP's question – and it won't work. The relationship between Customer and Order is many-to-many, so the query you've suggested (i.e., rehashed from the question) may return order products belonging to _more than one user_.

Comment: I appreciate the reply to this question. I found it very useful. In response to zeantsoi's comment, I have tested the second part of this answer and it does not work for me.

Comment: @zeantsoi - :).. I saw your post after I posted mine. But you did beat me to it. On Customer-Order, how do you see a many-many? `Order` is associated with a single customer, no? At least the schema seems to suggest that.

Comment: The models define a belongs-to/has-many relationship, but the `seeds.rb` suggests a many-to-many. This is primarily an issue with the data, rather than the code.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you order_products is meant to be a join table for orders and products. You might want to take a look at the `has_many :through` association as described here: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#the-has-many-through-association